# Angular 2 - Mark nested formbuilder as Touched

Tags: forms, nested, angular2-forms, formbuilder

I have the following problem: in my application I havea huge form with nested formbuilder in it, it works great and everything but when the user submits the form I want to mark the full form as Touched (to run validations), the code is the

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form= fb.group({
        field1: [null],
        field2: [null],
        nestedForm1: fb.group({
            field3: [null, Validators.required],
            field4: [null]
        }),
        nestedForm2: fb.group({
            field5: [null, Validators.required],
            field6: [null, Validators.required]
        })
    });
}
```

And when I run:

```
this.form.markAsTouched();
```

Only Field1 & Field2 get marked, is there a way I'm missing to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can create a custom method like below:

```
 setAsTouched(group: FormGroup | FormArray) {
  group.markAsTouched()
  for (let i in group.controls) {
    if (group.controls[i] instanceof FormControl) {
      group.controls[i].markAsTouched();
    } else {
      this.setAsTouched(group.controls[i]);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for, I can't upvote but I marked your answer as accepted, really really thank you.